# Querying ElasticSearch to order empty strings last

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using Django, Haystack, and ElasticSearch. I want to order my search results so that results where the ordered field value is empty ("") come after results where it is not empty. I cannot find an API in Haystack that can do this. The request sent to ElasticSearch looks like:

```
{
   "sort":[
      {
         "version":{
            "order":"asc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query":{
      ...
   }
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite this ElasticSearch query so that results with an empty string for "version" will come after results where "version" exists?

I have implemented this in Python as:

```
sorted(sqs, key=lambda x: getattr(x, 'version') == '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query assigns _score of 1.0 to all records with non-empty version and _score of 2.0 to all records with empty version. Then it sorts by _score in ascending order and then by version in ascending order. As a result, all records with empty version are pushed to the bottom of the list.

```
{
    "query": {
        "custom_filters_score" : {
            "query" : {
                "constant_score": {
                    "query": {
                        .... your original query ....                        
                    }
                }
            },
            "filters" : [
                {
                    "filter" : { "missing" : { "field" :  "version"} },
                    "boost" : "2"
                }
            ]
        }        
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {"order":"asc"}
        },
        {
            "version": {"order":"asc"}
        }
    ]
}
```